# What does "swept off their feet" mean?

Tags: meaning

> - Potential hazards of hurricanes:
> - Storm surges
> - **Possibility of persons being swept off their feet**
> - Drowning

(https://www.sagaftra.org/files/safety_bulletins_amptp_part_3_9_3.pdf)

There is a similar idiom, but that doesn't fit in this context. What does "swept off their feet" mean? Does it mean they could fell off by the wind?

Comment: You need to give more context for this. It is probably an attempt at humor, but you should probably link to the place you read this.

Comment: @Robusto More contexts are provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using the literal meaning of the phrase. A large wave crashes into a person, knocking them down and potentially carrying them out to sea.